# A word that describes different forms of the same word

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word that describes all forms of a root word (not being the past tense or past participle form)? In the instant case, the root word is "compare" and one of the different forms is "comparatively". But I want to refer to all of the different forms that "compare" could take. Please help me.

Comment: You could speak of *derivations*, or possibly *inflections* of the root word, perhaps qualified by an adjective *grammatical* or *conjugative*.

Comment: Generally the metaphor is that there is one root with several stems. So one speaks of the "perfect stem" or the "present stem" of a particular Latin verb root. E.g, _vidē-_ is the present stem and _vīd-_ is the perfect stem of the verb _vidēō, vidēre, vīdī, visum_ 'see'.

Comment: Inflection : a change in the form of a word that occurs when it has a particular use.

Answer (score 1):

Words like 'Accidence', 'declension' or 'conjugation' may be used for derivtional words. Of the three words suggested, the first two may be used for noun derivatives and the last for verb derivatives.

The modulation of a word can well be described by the term, 'inflexion' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Technically these are called lexemes or lemmas

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you improve this answer by adding any references or examples from actual usage?  If not, it may be down-voted or deleted.

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what is desired. a lexeme (or lemma) is the root itself. The OP is looking for the set of words that come from the one root.

Comment: You might coin a term like 'lexical morphate'.  Conjugations deal with TAM of verbs and derivations deal with casts between v., n., adj...